# AWS Route 53 - route to server outside of AWS Cloud

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Is it possible to route to a server outside of the AWS Cloud with a CNAME?

In this case it is my API that is sitting in a different cloud -> so can i route to api.example.com to this API?

(I have my domain on GoDaddy.com)

---

My settings:

[Image of my settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxO3n.png)

---

New setting:

[New settings according to answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1FOc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See the [Amazon Route 53 FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/?nc1=h_ls):

> Q. What is Amazon Route 53?
>
> Amazon Route 53 provides highly available and scalable Domain Name
>   System (DNS), domain name registration, and health-checking web
>   services. It is designed to give developers and businesses an
>   extremely reliable and cost effective way to route end users to
>   Internet applications by translating names like example.com into the
>   numeric IP addresses, such as 192.0.2.1, that computers use to connect
>   to each other. You can combine your DNS with health-checking services
>   to route traffic to healthy endpoints or to independently monitor
>   and/or alarm on endpoints. You can also purchase and manage domain
>   names such as example.com and automatically configure DNS settings for
>   your domains. Route 53 effectively connects user requests to
>   infrastructure running in AWS – such as Amazon EC2 instances, Elastic
>   Load Balancing load balancers, or Amazon S3 buckets – **and can also
>   be used to route users to infrastructure outside of AWS.**

Comment: to add to this.. You can have ALL the records be outside AWS with no issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot - do you have any idea then why this is not working? (see provided image)

Comment: @FabianLurz, the Alias value is wrong. See the example given there. You need to put a fqdn and not an url.

Comment: Thanks ;) It is still not working tough -> i guess it takes some time to get active right?

Comment: @FabianLurz, you need to put a domain name and not an ip address.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CNAMEFormat

Comment: I see - but tomcat doesn't give me a domain name - i only get an ip address. How to do that then?

Comment: @FabianLurz, well tomcat is not suppose to create domain name for you. You need to configure your nameserver for that. Alternativley, you can try to select Record type `A` and use the ip address to see if it works.

Comment: Hm also tried that - with the record type A. Still not working :(